# How can i pass large formatted text in a URL variable to use in a textarea?

Tags: php, url

I have a button in my Outlook addon that once pressed, will fire up a browser window and open a particular url. The url will contain parameters.

I have been able to browse successfully to URL's like so:

`www.example.com?id=10&subject=testing&sender=someEmail@email.com`

What i want to do is extract data from an email and pass it into a web form i have created. I have no issues using PHP to grab the data from the url using `$_GET[]` but i wonder how can i do this with formatted text (eg text that can contain bullet points and other non-standard characters).

Lets assume i have extracted text as is from an email and is very large. Can this be passed as a URL parameter and then placed in a `<textarea>`?

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the text from the email, or how to form the url, or both?

Are you the person that sent the email or is this intended to work on every email regardless of the sender?

Comment: I want to know if the data i extract from an email can be placed in the URL variable (including all special characters)

Comment: Simply put, yes, make sure you URL Encode it first then you can. See answer below from Harshit where he explains the limitation of Get and Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data remains URL encoded when passed through url GET method. 
You could pass any characters to the URL.

GET method only accepts 1024 characters to be passed. If you have more characters, you should use POST method.